# Writing Field Calculator codeblock using Python parser of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-pro, python-parser

The following code isn't working as expected and I'm not sure why:

```
  UpOrDown = reclass(!UpOrDown!) 
  def reclass (Z,GP):
   if (GP == "DT" and Z == "CG"):
    UpOrDown = 1
   if (GP == "DT" and Z == "CN"):
    UpOrDown = 1
   if (GP == ...and so on.... )
```

The expression is passing as valid but the wrning (warning 002858) suggests that there is a `TypeError` in `reclass()` which is missing the argument `'G'`.

[image]

I have added this into the code at `UpOrDown = reclass(!UpOrDown!,!G!)` which returns no error but doesn't output the expected variable of 1 in the `UpOrDown` column (which is Double).

I also changed the dependent variables to both Z and GP which still didn't change anything.

[image]

What is missing?

Comment: You have *one* argument `reclass(!UpOrDown!)` and two in the arglist `def reclass (Z,GP)` and you don't show what is returned. Look again at the documentation. 1) same number of arguments, 2) `return` a singleton value

Comment: I took your advice but it's still not working.

Comment: As @Vince mentioned, you need a return statement in your function. At the end, type `return UpOrDown`.

Comment: Please always provide errors as formatted text rather than pictures.  That way they are available to future searches by others stuck at the same place, and be easily readable on all devices.

Comment: You should also use `elif` in your conditional logic (or `return 1` instead of not returning the set variable)

Answer (score 2):

The field calculator needs to `return` a value that will be populated onto your field.  Your current code just sets a variable `UpOrDown`, it doesn't tell the calculator what to write.

Additionally you should use `elif` rather than `if` for your subsequent lines so that the parser only processes what it needs to, and then finish up with an `else` to handle what happens if none of the `if`/`elif` do anything.

```
reclass(!Parcels_Zoning_Interest_ZONINGABBREV!, !GPABBREVIATION!)
```

---

```
def reclass (Z,GP):
    if (GP == "DT" and Z == "CG"):
        UpOrDown = 1
    elif (GP == "DT" and Z == "CN"):
        UpOrDown = 2
    elif (GP ==  "this" and Z == "that" ):
        UpOrDown = 3
    else:
        UpOrDown = 0

    return UpOrDown
```